# Error: The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, password-recovery

While making the Password Reset page, using Firebase Auth. I have made a few pages using Firebase but never encountered this kind of error, please suggest a solution.
It shows an error:-

```
Error: The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.
lib/pages/forgot_pw_page.dart:82
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
                  onPressed: passwordReset(),
```

What I am doing wrong?

Code:

(I have trimmed the code, as it was not allowing to post whole)

```
class ForgotPasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ForgotPasswordPage> createState() => _ForgotPasswordPageState();
}

class _ForgotPasswordPageState extends State<ForgotPasswordPage> {
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future passwordReset() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailController.text.trim());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: passwordReset(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Maybe something is wrong here

```
  Future<void> passwordReset() async {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MaterialButton(
        // onPressed: () => passwordReset(),
        onPressed: passwordReset,  
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Material Button and all buttons in flutter at that only accept void functions. Those that just fire and don't return anything. In this case, resetPassword is a Future. For this case, you'll want to wrap it in a void function `() => resetPassword()`. Use this pattern for any function you declare that is not void. It's a really common error everyone faces occasionally